# как динамически выделить память под массив структур в Си

Tags: c, структуры

есть структура

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
    char number_of_group[8];
    double score;
};
```

это лаба моя. там предполагается менюшка

```
    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("1 - input\n");
    printf("2 - output\n");
    printf("3 - data processing\n");
    printf("4 - stop and exit\n");
```

там я перехожу в подменюшку для ввода

```
    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("1 - console input\n");
    printf("2 - file input\n");
    printf("3 - random input\n");
    printf("4 - back to main menu\n");
```

в разных подменюшках разное считываение количества элементов
поэтому в каждой надо выделить память.
изначально я в мейне объявляю структуру
struct student *mephist;
как мне выделить динамически память подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: массив структур*

Comment: С помощью функции `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделить память под структуру

```
struct student *mephist = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

если пишется код, который и под плюсы будет компилироваться, то где то так

```
struct student *mephist = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

Если же нужно выделить память под несколько элементов массива, тогда просто нужно домножить

```
int n = 100; // под 100 элементов
struct student *mephist = malloc(n*sizeof(struct student));
mephist[99] - последний элемент
```

также есть хорошая штука calloc

```
int n = 100; // под 100 элементов
struct student *mephist = calloc(n, sizeof(struct student));
```

calloc хорош тем, что у него кол-во элементов и размер структуры задаются отдельными параметрами и он зануляет массив (очень часто ошибки возникают из за того, что массив не был занулен и содержал мусор)

Comment: понял. спасибо большое!

Comment: а если у меня массив структур, то это struct student *mephist = malloc(n*sizeof(struct student)); я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да да, где n - это размер этого массива

Comment: спасибо! разобрался